# How to replace links on blog posts Shopify

Tags: shopify, blogs

I recently created a copy of my website from here https://www.thecolorkind.com/ to here:  https://colorkindstudio.com/ and I moved all the blogs to this last domain but they have some links that still redirect to the old domain.

We have more than 200 posts and it will take sometime to update/replace each link on each post. So, is there a way to replace all the links on my blog posts https://colorkindstudio.com/blogs/news to have the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

I have two approach to solve this.

1. You redirect/forward all the request from https://www.thecolorkind.com/ to https://colorkindstudio.com/
   If you are using GoDaddy then this might help - https://in.godaddy.com/help/forward-my-domain-12123
2. Second approach is to use some JavaScript to see if an anchor tag have thecolorkind.com in it's href attribute and if it does then replace the link with colorkindstudio.com.

Let me know if tis helps or if you need more insights.

Comment: hey @kalpit shah I have place a forward redirection from old domain to new one but it doesn't work they way I wanted to so maybe i'd like to try your second suggestion. I might have to do a research about how to do it. Or do you have any suggesting code?